# How can I implement actionbar to api level 8 easily?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I search on google and stackoverflow this topic.I ve found a few way to implement.
one of these is  **actionbarsherlock** , but actually I do not understand how can implement this to my project. Is there any simple way? I mean a few classes or just add a library I do not know but I have a huge project and I want to implement this .Could you show me how can do it easily?

thanks

Comment: Plesae check my answer bellow. Its not much complicated as actionbarsherlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).
You can use android support library for this. No need of any other library.

Example also there in side link.

Comment: thank you very much for answer but sorry I do not understand what is suppored library , I use android library **android-support-v4.jar** instead of this should I use another one and how can I download that library

Comment: By using android SDK manager, inside Extra, upgrade Android Support Library.

Comment: Use [link](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html). It will help you to setup for support library.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `ActionbarCompat` library.

1) `Import` the `ActionbarCompat` library project into your workspace first and add the library to your project

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

2) Extend your Activity Class with `ActionBarActivity`

3) set your theme in manifest as

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want to use ActionBar that supports devices with lower api..
you can do two things ...
1)Use the support Library([ActionbarCompat](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)) 
2)Use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

I use ActionBarsherlock

Steps to Use

1)`YOURACTIVITY extends SherlockActivity`

2) Use `onCreateOptionsMenu` to get the menu


`

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("");
        subMenu1.add(0,2,Menu.NONE,"Rate Us").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_good);


        MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();
        subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_overflow);
        subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

3) Use `onOptionsItemSelected` to get the item selected

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 2:
            //rate app

            break;
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

4)Finally in your `AndroidManifest` File, add this under your activity

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
```

`

5) and you are Done ...:)

Answer (score 1):

For setup support library see-

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

And for implementing action bar using support library see this-

http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-how-to-use/

Comment: @user3086226 From second link you see its very simple code.

Comment: @user3086226 mine pleasure. If you need any more help you can ask me. Recently I've worked on same thing.